# Audit Logs on O365: SitePermissionsModified deprecated?

Tags: office-365, audit-log-reports

I need to check who changed permissions on a specific and unique group on sharepoint. Audit logs gives me no results and on the Microsoft page I get the following note:

(Site administrator or owner (or system account) changes the permission level that are assigned to a group on a site. This activity is also logged if all permissions are removed from a group.)

Note: This operation has been deprecated in SharePoint Online. To find related events, you can search for other permission-related activities such as Added site collection admin, Added user or group to SharePoint group, Allowed user to create groups, Created group, and Deleted group.

Looking at this type of information is very frequent and useful, what is there to do to find out who changed the permissions of a group? (example added contribute to Read?)